# Hangman Game - failing to print string characters at the correct position

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create a hangman game. I think I've gotten fairly far on my own by just doing some basic game logic. But it's failing to print the guess at the appropriate spot within the string.

For example, if the word is 'pitch' and the user guesses 't', it will print the 't' at the index of 0 rather than the index it actually is. Right now I'm printing with charAt(x), but I've tried indexOf and that doesn't seem to work either.

Any thoughts?

JS:

```
// creating array of random words

var words = ["evaluate", "leader", "glory", "thanks", "pit", "sign", "neighborhood", "twist", "beneficiary", "giant", "bargain", "analyst", "embark", "competition", "bench", "impress", "tick", "elegant", "wing", "spring", "rider", "romantic", "confuse", "arrange", "critic", "quiet", "raise", "paradox", "inject", "gallery"];
var randWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var randWordLngth = randWord.length;

console.log('The random word is ' + randWord + " and the length is " + randWordLngth);

var temp = '';

// printing an empty space for each character in the word length
for(var i = 0; i < randWordLngth; i++){
    temp = temp + '___ ';
}

$('#wordBox').html(temp);


$('#subBTN').click(function(){
    // get user input
    var userInput = $('input').val();
    // clear input field after capturing data
    $('input').val('');

    // check if input matches a charater in the random word
    var wordCheck = randWord.indexOf(userInput);
    console.log(wordCheck);

    //if userInput character is in the string, print character at its position to html
    if(wordCheck >= 0) {
        $('#wordBox').html(randWord.charAt(wordCheck) + temp);
    } else {
        $('.list-group').append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + randWord.charAt(wordCheck) + "</li>");
    }

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
            <div class="col-sm-6">
                <div id="wordBox" class="row pt-5"></div>
                <div id="inputBox" class="row pt-5">
                    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                    <div class="col-sm-8">
                        <div class="input-group mb-3">
                            <input type="text" id="guessBox" class="form-control" placeholder="Guess a letter...ex: 'a', 'b', 'c'...">
                            <div class="input-group-append">
                              <button class="btn btn-outline-secondary" id="subBTN" type="button">Go!</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-sm-2"></div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-3"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="row" style="border: 1px solid; height: 300px">
            <div id="wrongLtrs" class="col-sm-6" style="border: 1px solid">
                <h3 class="card-title text-center pt-3">Incorrect Guesses</h3>
                <ul class="list-group"> 
                    <!-- where the wrong guesses go as a list -->
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-6"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have a few hurdles here.

1. indexOf will only return the location of the first occurrence. You should put that in a loop.
2. You aren't keeping track of the word that exists as it is guessed. Have two strings - one with the answer to find and one with what has been found. They mask each other. E.G. randWord might = "neighb.rh..d" and guessedWord = "......o..oo."
3. Replace the empty spots on the guessed word with your blanks so that the spacing is correct: e.g. guessedWord.replace(".", "___ ");

This is just one set of suggestions - there are other approaches out there, but I figure this would produce the simplest resolve given what you've already worked out.

Here's an example of what your code might look like after working out all these changes...

*(Note - This is untested - it's just to get you in the ballpark)*:

```
// creating array of random words

var words = ["evaluate", "leader", "glory", "thanks", "pit", "sign", "neighborhood", "twist", "beneficiary", "giant", "bargain", "analyst", "embark", "competition", "bench", "impress", "tick", "elegant", "wing", "spring", "rider", "romantic", "confuse", "arrange", "critic", "quiet", "raise", "paradox", "inject", "gallery"];
var randWord = words[Math.floor(Math.random() * words.length)];
var guessedWord = randWord.replace(/./, "."); /** Create a variable string of periods to denote an unguessed letter. **/
var randWordLngth = randWord.length;

console.log('The random word is ' + randWord + " and the length is " + randWordLngth);

var temp = '';

$('#wordBox').html(temp);


$('#subBTN').click(function(){
    // get user input
    var userInput = $('input').val();
    // clear input field after capturing data
    $('input').val('');

    // check if input matches a charater in the random word
    var wordCheck = randWord.indexOf(userInput);
    while (wordCheck >= 0) {
        console.log(wordCheck);
        guessedWord = guessedWord.substr(0, wordCheck) + userInput + guessedWord.substr(wordCheck + 1);
        randWord = randWord.substr(0, wordCheck) + "." + randWord.substr(wordCheck + 1);
        wordCheck = randWord.indexOf(userInput);
    }

    //if userInput character is in the string, print character at its position to html
    if(wordCheck >= 0) {
        // printing an empty space for each character in the word length
        $('#wordBox').html(guessedWord.replace(".", "___ ").replace(/([a-z])/i, "_$1_ "));
    } else {
        $('.list-group').append("<li class='list-group-item'>" + randWord.charAt(wordCheck) + "</li>");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This line will always print the character at position 0 + whatever is on variable temp:
$('#wordBox').html(randWord.charAt(wordCheck) + temp);

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is this line:
`$('#wordBox').html(randWord.charAt(wordCheck) + temp);`

It's just changing the contents of the #wordBox to be the guessed letter then the temp variable, which in this case, is 4 blank spaces.

You need to store the correctly guessed letters (ie: in an array) and use them to recalculate the temp variable every time the player guesses a letter correctly.

Comment: oh I see. Yeah, that makes sense. I'll probably need an "incorrect" array too to print those as well.